# QTableView разные триггеры редактирования для разных столбцов

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, меню, qtableview

Хочу сделать разные триггеры редактирования для разных столбцов в QTableView.
Вьюха смотрит на модель, наследованную от `QFileSystemModel`, в этой модели есть дополнительный столбец, в этом столбце `QComboBox` через делегат.

Я ставлю флаги `(QFileSystemModel::flags(index) | Qt::ItemIsEditable);` и вешаю триггеры редактирования выбираемого объекта `TableView->setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::CurrentChanged);` на представлении.

С `QComboBox` все классно, но при этом, я бы хотел, чтобы первый столбец на представлении (Файл из `QFileSystemModel`) не редактировался таким образом, но был доступен для редактирования по `ПКМ`->переименовать (контекстное меню уже заготовлено)

Answer (score 0):

Пытался решить задачу по разному, с флагами думал что-то, но ни к чему не пришел. В итоге, решение было основано на состоянии QSelectionModel:

Для начала, тригеры изменения вообще отключил (чтобы 1 столбец был всегда в правильном состоянии)

```
TableView->setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::NoEditTriggers);
m_pFileSystemModel->setReadOnly(false);
```

Флаги модели:

```
    if (index.column() == 4)
    return (QFileSystemModel::flags(index) | Qt::ItemIsEditable);
return QFileSystemModel::flags(index);
```

Решение проблемы:

```
    connect(TableView->selectionModel(), &QItemSelectionModel::currentChanged, this, [this]() {
    if (TableView->currentIndex().column() == 4)
        m_pTableView->edit(m_pTableView->currentIndex());
});
```

В таком виде для 4 столбца сразу встает edit(). edit() для 1 столбца вызывается по CustomMenuRequest(). Всем спасибо, кто над этим задумался.

Answer (score 0):

Конструктор главного окна приложения (для примера):

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    // Сама модель
    QFileSystemModel *model = new QFileSystemModel();
    model->setRootPath(QDir::currentPath());
    // Можно редактировать
    model->setReadOnly(false);

    ui->treeView->setModel(model);

    // Мы будем создавать свое контекстное меню
    ui->treeView->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu);

    // На ПКМ вызовется этот сигнал
    connect(ui->treeView, &QTreeView::customContextMenuRequested, [&](const QPoint& pos) {
        // Получаем индекс по координатам
        QModelIndex index = ui->treeView->indexAt(pos);
        // если это первый столбец, то
        if (index.column() == 0) {
            QMenu menu;
            // На пункт "Переименовать" вешаем лямбду, в которой вызываем редактирование выбранного индекса
            menu.addAction(tr("Переименовать"), ui->treeView, [&, index]() {
                ui->treeView->edit(index);
            });
            menu.addSeparator();
            menu.addAction(tr("Свойства"));
            // Меню перемещаем и показываем по координатам курсора
            menu.exec(ui->treeView->viewport()->mapToGlobal(pos));
        }
    });
}
```

Проверено на Qt 6.1.0

Comment: Да, но при этом четвертый столбец должен редактироваться при одинарном нажатии (как при `TableView->setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::CurrentChanged);`, а первый ТОЛЬКО через контекстное меню.

Comment: @ff00000000x00 так сделайте как вам надо. Я лишь показал как сделать контекстное меню для ПКМ